# Batch Reprojection; ArcPy script runs in IDE but not as a tool, gives ERROR 000208: Error creating output feature class Failed to execute (Project)

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, error-000208

My goal is to write a script that selects a shapefile, grabs the SpatialReference from it, then reproject all the shapefiles in a specific folder with that SpatialReference. When running from IDE it seems to work;

```
    import arcpy
    import os

    # Environment Setup
    arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\myUsername\workingdirectory"
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    inputLayer = r"C:\Users\myUsername\workingdirectory\Shapefile.shp"
    outputFolder = r"C:\Users\myUsername\workingdirectory\Output"
    targetCRS = arcpy.Describe(inputLayer).spatialReference.name

    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():

        # check if there are any feature classes without a defined coordinate system
        crscheck = arcpy.Describe(fc)
        print(fc)

        # skip if CRS is unassigned
        if crscheck.spatialReference.Name == "Unknown":
            print ("No assigned CRS, skipping the file: " + fc)

        else:
            # Determine the new output feature class path and name
            outfc = os.path.join(outputFolder, fc)

            # run project tool
            arcpy.Project_management(fc, outfc, targetCRS)

            # check messages
            print(arcpy.GetMessages())
```

But when I try to turn this into an ArcGIS Pro tool by changing input, output and workspace to GetParameterAsText functions and run it from the ArcGIS Pro selecting the exact same folder options it fails.

The only thing happens is my Output folder gets deleted from the directory when I run the tool.

Update: I have also changed working directory to a folder selection using Arcpy;

> targetCRS = arcpy.Describe(inputLayer).spatialReference
> AttributeError: DescribeData: Method spatialReference does not exist

```
import arcpy
import os
#%%
# Environment Setup
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

inputLayer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.AddMessage("InputLayer="+inputLayer)
inputFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
arcpy.AddMessage("inputFolder="+inputFolder)
outputFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
arcpy.AddMessage("OutputFolder="+outputFolder)


#%%

targetCRS = arcpy.Describe(inputLayer).spatialReference

for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():

    # check if there are any feature classes without a defined coordinate system
    crscheck = arcpy.Describe(fc)

    # skip if CRS is unassigned
    if crscheck.spatialReference.Name == "Unknown":
        arcpy.AddMessage("No assigned CRS, skipping the file: " + fc)

    else:
        # Determine the new output feature class path and name
        outfc = os.path.join(outputFolder, fc)

        # run project tool
        arcpy.Project_management(fc, outfc, targetCRS)
        #
        # # check messages
        arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages())
```

Comment: You've got diagnostic `print` statements instead of using `arcpy.AddMessage`.

Comment: How do you use inputfolder?

Comment: I believe inputFolder is useless so I removed it. 

My new code is as below but it doesn't work, the error indicates "Method SpatialReference does not exist"

I also changed the print statements to arcpy.AddMessage

Comment: It should be spatial not Spatial

Comment: Thank you; in my script they are all written as spatialReference but the error returned SpatialReference. Although, currently for the last version of the script as I updated in the question, I'm back to "ERROR 000208: Error creating output feature class Failed to execute (Project)"

Comment: What type of patameter outputolder? Output or input?

Comment: I have tried Feature Dataset and Shapefile options for Input and I'm selecting Folder option for output.